# Url in side of svg xmlns

Tags: javascript, html, svg, xpath, xml-namespaces

I am trying to find url of this image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfi6M.png
Page url:https://jobs.tnaa.com/jobsearch/results?Page=1&occupation=RN&city=&radius=20&state1=ALL&specialty=&GeoType=State

But there is no link except then svg xmlns. Can someone explain me what how can i find the url to this image and what is svg xmlns?

```html
<a href="https://tnaa.com" class="logo logo--primary">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/6000/png" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 105 105">
            <path d="M473.85,66a1.29,1.29,0,0,1-.05-.24c0-.18,0-.36,0-.53V24a2.08,2.08,0,0,1,.06-.74,1.54,1.54,0,0,1,.3,0H578a2.79,2.79,0,0,1,.75.05c0,.1,0,.19,0,.28s0,.29,0,.44V81.33c0,.23,0,.45,0,.7a2.37,2.37,0,0,1-.31.06h-5.31l-.24,0-.22-.48Q569.49,74,566.3,66.5c-.07-.17-.15-.33-.22-.47-.53-.06-7.43-.06-7.88,0-.42.91-.8,1.86-1.2,2.81s-.8,1.89-1.2,2.83l-1.2,2.84-1.2,2.84c-.39.94-.8,1.89-1.2,2.83S551.41,82.08,551,83s-.78,1.89-1.24,2.9c-.61-1.4-1.16-2.72-1.71-4l-1.68-4-1.67-4L543,70l-1.68-4A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,541,66h-7.34l-.15,0c-.19.1-.21.29-.28.45L531.5,70.6l-7.2,17.07c0,.12-.11.23-.15.34s-.11-.09-.11-.14,0-.29,0-.43V66.66A1.6,1.6,0,0,0,524,66l-.47,0c-3.52,0-6.33,0-6.7.05-.13.16-.08.34-.08.52l.06,4.69.09,8.62a5.45,5.45,0,0,1,0,.56,1,1,0,0,1-.36-.39l-4.34-5.92-5.63-7.68-.15-.2a.5.5,0,0,0-.51-.26,4.51,4.51,0,0,1-.52,0H474.53A2.64,2.64,0,0,1,473.85,66Zm0,6.3q0,24.19,0,48.38a1.16,1.16,0,0,0,0,.18,1.52,1.52,0,0,0,.73.07H578c.15,0,.31,0,.47,0s.19,0,.31-.07V88.35c0-.15,0-.29,0-.44a1.64,1.64,0,0,0-.07-.28h-3.25a.7.7,0,0,0-.17.06c.06.14.1.27.16.41.41,1,.83,2,1.25,3,.05.13.15.25.09.42a1.81,1.81,0,0,1-.61.06H569.7a2.24,2.24,0,0,1-.31-.05l-.06-.07a.36.36,0,0,1,0-.09l-.06-.13q-3.4-8.86-6.83-17.72l-.12-.32a.08.08,0,0,0,0,0l0-.09s0,0,0,0h0s-.07,0-.07.06q-1.67,4.38-3.31,8.76a.38.38,0,0,0,0,.15,1.18,1.18,0,0,0,.56,0c1,0,1.94,0,2.91,0l.56,0a1.73,1.73,0,0,1,.12.2c.59,1.68,1.17,3.37,1.76,5.06a1.23,1.23,0,0,1,0,.19,1,1,0,0,1-.57.06H556.5c-.56,1.32-1,2.65-1.58,4a1.7,1.7,0,0,1-.28,0H544.9a1.7,1.7,0,0,1-.28,0c-.07-.16-.15-.32-.21-.48-.39-1-.78-2-1.18-3-.06-.16-.08-.35-.25-.45-.7,0-10.8,0-11.24,0-.07.16-.15.33-.22.51-.38,1-.76,2-1.15,3-.07.16-.09.35-.29.48l-.65,0H517.87c-.88,0-.68.07-1.16-.59l-8.28-11.27-1.68-2.28c-.05-.07-.09-.18-.25-.15a9.26,9.26,0,0,0,0,1.29c0,.42,0,.84,0,1.26s0,.87,0,1.31,0,.87,0,1.31,0,.87,0,1.3,0,.84,0,1.26,0,.87,0,1.31l0,1.31c0,.43,0,.87,0,1.3s0,.84,0,1.26a8.5,8.5,0,0,1,0,1.33,4.07,4.07,0,0,1-.47,0h-6.3a.75.75,0,0,1-.48-.09,2.45,2.45,0,0,1,0-.61V72.93c0-.16,0-.32,0-.49s0-.21,0-.32a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-.69-.06H474.11a1.87,1.87,0,0,0-.25,0A.65.65,0,0,0,473.81,72.25Zm9.64,19.3-.54,0c0-.11,0-.2-.05-.3s0-.22,0-.33c0-5.33,0-10.65,0-16a1.5,1.5,0,0,1,0-.56,1,1,0,0,1,.53-.07c2.06,0,4.13,0,6.19,0a.91.91,0,0,1,.53.08c0,.11,0,.24,0,.36.07,4.11,0,16.25-.05,16.76C489.66,91.57,487.27,91.59,483.45,91.55Zm28.94,32.08H474.13a2.3,2.3,0,0,0-.28.06,11,11,0,0,0,0,2.56l.71,0h38.2a2.3,2.3,0,0,0,.28-.06,16.83,16.83,0,0,0,0-2.56Zm24.79-50.24c-.54,1.41-1.07,2.82-1.6,4.24s-1,2.62-1.48,3.92c-.05.13-.14.26-.07.41.4.05,5.51.09,6.51,0a2.11,2.11,0,0,0,.28,0c-.05-.15-.09-.29-.14-.43-1.39-3.81-3.1-8.25-3.3-8.58A3.46,3.46,0,0,0,537.18,73.39Zm35.06,54c-.14-.2-.3-.39-.43-.6a1.77,1.77,0,0,1-.36-.59l.38-.27a1.9,1.9,0,0,0,.63-.75,2.08,2.08,0,0,0-1.39-2.9,4.21,4.21,0,0,0-1.17-.19c-.89,0-1.77,0-2.66,0a1.43,1.43,0,0,0-.28.07c0,.09,0,.15,0,.21,0,1.79,0,3.59,0,5.38a2.07,2.07,0,0,0,0,.3c.3,0,.57,0,.85,0a1.56,1.56,0,0,0,.8-.08c.09-.49,0-1,.08-1.44.85-.17.95-.13,1.39.48l.38.52.4.52h1.52l.28,0Zm-3.52-4a2,2,0,0,1,.28,0,7.22,7.22,0,0,1,.93,0,.93.93,0,0,1,.9.6.87.87,0,0,1-.73,1.17,3.69,3.69,0,0,1-1.37,0A6,6,0,0,1,568.72,123.47Zm-50.33.88a3.07,3.07,0,0,1-.85.06h-.78a2.69,2.69,0,0,1-.84-.06,5.42,5.42,0,0,1,0-1.06,5.76,5.76,0,0,0,0-1.1,4.36,4.36,0,0,0-1.69,0c0,.46,0,1,0,1.43s0,1,0,1.45,0,1,0,1.5a13.61,13.61,0,0,0,0,1.43,4.15,4.15,0,0,0,1.69,0c0-.35,0-.72,0-1.09a5.9,5.9,0,0,1,0-1.11,2.76,2.76,0,0,1,.85,0q.39,0,.78,0a2.28,2.28,0,0,1,.82.06,6,6,0,0,1,0,1.11,6.71,6.71,0,0,0,0,1.1,4,4,0,0,0,1.66,0,2.4,2.4,0,0,0,0-.28c0-1.75,0-3.51,0-5.27a2.19,2.19,0,0,0,0-.27,4.92,4.92,0,0,0-1.67,0C518.38,122.92,518.46,123.63,518.39,124.35Zm29,3.66c0-.14,0-.3,0-.46v-1.4c0-.13,0-.26.1-.36a11.68,11.68,0,0,1,2.38,0,.76.76,0,0,1,.06.47c0,.48,0,1,0,1.45a1.61,1.61,0,0,0,.06.35,9.72,9.72,0,0,0,1.62,0,1.07,1.07,0,0,0,0-.21c0-1.83,0-3.65,0-5.47a.59.59,0,0,0-.05-.19,1.24,1.24,0,0,0-.57-.06,4.51,4.51,0,0,0-.52,0c-.18,0-.38-.05-.57.1,0,.13,0,.27,0,.41,0,.47,0,.94,0,1.41a2.21,2.21,0,0,1-.05.33,7.2,7.2,0,0,1-1.22,0,3.54,3.54,0,0,1-1.25-.08c0-.17,0-.33,0-.49v-1.35c0-.11,0-.21,0-.34-.48,0-.93,0-1.38,0a1.07,1.07,0,0,0-.27.07c-.07.62-.05,5.46,0,5.86A5.23,5.23,0,0,0,547.4,128Zm-22-3.54c-.57,0-1.14,0-1.71,0-.16,0-.32,0-.46-.11a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.06-1l.52,0h2.08a.81.81,0,0,0,.52-.09,4,4,0,0,0,0-1.14,1.6,1.6,0,0,0-.27,0h-4.32a1.59,1.59,0,0,0-.3.06c0,.09,0,.15,0,.21,0,1.81,0,3.62,0,5.42a1,1,0,0,0,0,.24,1.6,1.6,0,0,0,.27,0h4.43a1.77,1.77,0,0,0,.3-.06,3.35,3.35,0,0,0-.05-1.18h-2.83l-.41,0a2.91,2.91,0,0,1,0-1.1l.53,0h1.82a.47.47,0,0,0,.41-.12,5,5,0,0,0,0-1A1.94,1.94,0,0,0,525.44,124.47Zm50,1.3a.81.81,0,0,1,.52-.1c.61,0,1.22,0,1.82,0,.14,0,.27,0,.42,0a2.17,2.17,0,0,0,0-1.13l-.53,0H576a.89.89,0,0,1-.51-.07,1.8,1.8,0,0,1,0-1,1,1,0,0,1,.5-.06h2.19a.57.57,0,0,0,.47-.12c0-.16,0-.35,0-.55a1.4,1.4,0,0,0,0-.57l-.38,0h-4.06c-.15,0-.32,0-.44.11s0,.09,0,.13v5.47a.79.79,0,0,0,.06.22c.42,0,3.57.08,4.65,0a2,2,0,0,0,.32,0,3.34,3.34,0,0,0,0-1.18c-.55,0-1.09,0-1.62,0a13,13,0,0,1-1.64,0A3.23,3.23,0,0,1,575.47,125.77Zm-41.35,2c-.15-.33-.3-.65-.46-1-.66-1.4-1.31-2.8-2-4.21a.86.86,0,0,0-.29-.45h-1.63c-.06.12-.14.23-.19.34-.17.36-.34.71-.5,1.07-.63,1.34-1.27,2.68-1.89,4-.07.15-.2.3-.14.48a5.62,5.62,0,0,0,1.67,0,12,12,0,0,1,.55-1.07l.22,0c.71,0,1.42,0,2.13,0a.46.46,0,0,1,.5.33c.1.27.23.53.34.79a7.32,7.32,0,0,0,1.75,0A2.13,2.13,0,0,0,534.12,127.77Zm-2.74-2.12a.65.65,0,0,1-.17.08,6.8,6.8,0,0,1-1.42,0,8.52,8.52,0,0,1,.57-1.46c0-.13.06-.29.23-.36A8.33,8.33,0,0,1,531.38,125.65Zm34.83,2.2c-.35-.85-2.52-5.39-2.73-5.69a6.19,6.19,0,0,0-1.73,0l-2.63,5.61a1.42,1.42,0,0,0-.07.22,4.91,4.91,0,0,0,1.71,0c.23-.33.28-.75.54-1.06a19.91,19.91,0,0,1,2.68,0c.27.32.29.77.57,1.09a6.6,6.6,0,0,0,1.69,0A1.13,1.13,0,0,0,566.21,127.85Zm-2.79-2.21c-.13.15-.32.09-.48.1a5.42,5.42,0,0,1-.57,0,.85.85,0,0,1-.53-.09,3.88,3.88,0,0,1,.34-.89c.12-.29.25-.59.41-.94A7.06,7.06,0,0,1,563.42,125.64ZM558,122.4a4,4,0,0,0-2.32-.36,3.52,3.52,0,0,0-1.59.55,2.89,2.89,0,0,0-1.37,2.62,3,3,0,0,0,2.24,2.84,4.38,4.38,0,0,0,2.46,0,2.92,2.92,0,0,0,1.27-.72,1.35,1.35,0,0,0,.18-.25l-.51-.44c-.18-.14-.32-.34-.54-.4l-.08,0-.2.15a1.94,1.94,0,0,1-1.49.42,1.62,1.62,0,0,1-1.38-.89,1.75,1.75,0,0,1-.16-1.23,1.69,1.69,0,0,1,1.65-1.37,1.94,1.94,0,0,1,1.3.38l.37.27a7,7,0,0,0,1-.91A2.24,2.24,0,0,0,558,122.4ZM541.23,124v3.49a.81.81,0,0,0,.1.55,3.44,3.44,0,0,0,.79,0,1.64,1.64,0,0,0,.84-.1c0-.18,0-.37,0-.57,0-1.13,0-2.25,0-3.38a.89.89,0,0,1,.09-.59c.12,0,.26,0,.39,0h1.09a2.71,2.71,0,0,0,.37,0c0-.29,0-.57,0-.84a3.16,3.16,0,0,0,0-.32.71.71,0,0,0-.47-.08,47.82,47.82,0,0,0-5.1.07,2.79,2.79,0,0,0,0,1,.48.48,0,0,0,.09.21c.6,0,1.19,0,1.84,0C541.22,123.68,541.23,123.86,541.23,124Zm-2.1,2.79h-2.29a.21.21,0,0,1-.21-.18,3.24,3.24,0,0,1,0-.44v-3.48a1.14,1.14,0,0,0-.07-.56,9.66,9.66,0,0,0-1.32,0,2,2,0,0,0-.28,0c-.09.41-.11,2.83-.07,5.48,0,.13,0,.25,0,.39a1.31,1.31,0,0,0,.22.05h4.37a.46.46,0,0,0,.16-.06,1.13,1.13,0,0,0,0-.18v-.94A1.17,1.17,0,0,0,539.13,126.82Z" transform="translate(-473.79 -23.23)">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no url for the image, that is an SVG, the entire image is drawn in the `<path ....>`

To use that image just copy the SVG, that is everything from:

```
<svg xmlns="....

</svg>
```

Comment: is there a way to convert this svg path into an image like png or jpeg?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of tools that can assist with this, here is one: https://mybyways.com/blog/convert-svg-to-png-using-your-browser

Comment: Thank you for your help I now understand what is svg path and how to convert it. Thanks